# HikariCP without Framework

Tags: java, mysql, hikaricp

I am using HikariCP for the first time with Java but not using any backend framework or JPA.

My project have the following package structure

```
----db
----controllers
----views
----models
----handlers
```

In `db.DBManager.java` is where hikari datasource is set:

```
public class DBManager {
final protected HikariDataSource hikariDS;
protected Connection connection = null;

public DBManager() {

    String resourceName = "re/iprocu/coperativeerp/config/db/dbSettings.properties"; // could also be a constant
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try(InputStream resourceStream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)) {
        props.load(resourceStream);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    final HikariConfig hikariConfig = new  HikariConfig(props);
    //hikariConfig.setConnectionInitSql(absoluteFilePath);
    hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(30);
    hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(10);
    hikariConfig.setPoolName("TripPool");
    hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(1000);
    hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    hikariConfig.setAutoCommit(true);
    hikariConfig.setInitializationFailFast(false);
    hikariConfig.setLeakDetectionThreshold(2000);
    this.hikariDS = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
}
}
```

In `handlers`package is where queries to db is placed. 
Handler classes extend DBManager to get initialised hikari datasource.

```
package re.iprocu.coperativeerp.handlers;
public class InventoryHandler extends DBManager{

   final static private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SupplierHandler.class.getName());

public InventoryHandler(){
    super();
} 


public int addProductToInventory(Inventory inv){
    int key = 0;

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        connection  = hikariDS.getConnection();
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.executeUpdate();

        generatedKeys = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (generatedKeys != null && generatedKeys.next()) {
            key = generatedKeys.getInt(1);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Key");
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){ e.printStackTrace();}
    finally{
        if( connection != null ){
            try {connection.close();} 
            catch (SQLException ex) {logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
        }
        if( ps != null){
            try { ps.close();} 
            catch (SQLException ex) { logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
        }
    }

    return key;
}
}
```

In `controllers`package i define and initialize the handlers i need to use, and call the respective methods.

The problem is after is refresh ui or sometimes load for first time, throws and error `java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: TripPool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 1001ms.`

`Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"`

Based on my project structure, what is the best way for me to configure HikariCP and maximise it`s use

### Edit:

I found this stackoverflow [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738525/preparestatement-commit-sequence-not-working-in-mysql-hikaricp-webapp?rq=1) it works for me though my worry is the solution has a `Double-checked locking` problem that was not solved in the discussion and i don't know how to do it

Comment: How many instances of Hikari?  What web server are you using?

Comment: Installed XAMPP, so using Apache.... Hikari instances, i am not sure but i guess with the way i call my DBManager which creates Hikari, is many? How can i maintain it?

Comment: Each class instance you create recreates the datasource, basically adding 10 connections each time. You should create the `DataSource` once and reuse throughout your application.

Comment: Woah! Mind openning...

Comment: I updated a link to a stackoverflow question that does that, maintain one instance of DataSource...though according to an accepted answer a `Double-checked locking` problem might occur which i still don't know how to solve...could you?

Comment: Why do you ever need more than 1 connection?  Apache has a `MaxClients` -- decrease that _and_ decrease the 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error messages says, that your Database has too many connections currently opened. So first thing you can consult your DB documentation and increase connections limit. Or talk to you DB admin, if you have one.

The probable reason is that you create new datasource for every new instance of any subclass of `DBManager`. Make your `hikariDS` a static field and initialise it in static block:

```
public class DBManager {
  public static final HikariDataSource hikariDS;

  static {
    String resourceName = "re/iprocu/coperativeerp/config/db/dbSettings.properties";
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try(InputStream resourceStream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)) {
      props.load(resourceStream);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(DBManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    final HikariConfig hikariConfig = new  HikariConfig(props);
    hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(30);
    hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(10);
    hikariConfig.setPoolName("TripPool");
    hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(1000);
    hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    hikariConfig.setAutoCommit(true);
    hikariConfig.setInitializationFailFast(false);
    hikariConfig.setLeakDetectionThreshold(2000);
    DBManager.hikariDS = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
  }
}
```

I also removed `connection` field. You better storing it in method's local variable.

Comment: No DB admin, its just me...making connection pool smaller did not solve the problem. I guess maybe its the way i create the pool itself?Any suggestions on that side?

Comment: Seems to be Ok to me... Have you tried to increase connection limit in your DB

Comment: As M. Deinum comment says the problem of too many connections comes  because i create many instances of `HikariDataSource` which in every creation, 10 connections are added.

Comment: I updated a link to a stackoverflow question that does that, maintain one instance of DataSource...though according to an accepted answer a Double-checked locking problem might occur which i still don't know how to solve...could you?

Comment: @YunusEinsteinium I have updated my answer. I believe I now understand the real root cause of your troubles :)

Comment: instead of initializing it in a constructor i use static block, so you mean the class will have no constructor?... and a quick question...is the method you suggesting thread safe?

Comment: Yes, static block initialisation is always thread safe. And your `DBManager` will still have default empty constructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117327/discussion-between-yunus-einsteinium-and-nikem).